# Static on Mic line in when using EOS Utility on 600d

Tags: audio, canon

I've noticed quite a loud static noise on the line in of my camera when recording with EOS Utility. I've tried using different cabled for everything, and it works fine when the computer is not plugged in, or when it is, internal audio works fine. This one really has baffled me, and no matter what I do, it seems to persist. Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion, and it works! Again, thanks very much.

Comment: You are welcome. I re-posted it as an answer so that you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer is probably inducing interference on the unbalanced mic cable. Try putting a [ferrite bead/choke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead) on the tethering cable.